# Converting relative paths to absolute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<a href="/">1</a> // link to http://site.com
<a href="/section/page/">2/a> // link to http://site.com/section/page/
<a href="http://site.com/">3</a>
<a href="../gallery/1/">4</a> // link to http://site.com/gallery/1/
```

JS:

```
$("a").live('click', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    //do something
});
```

How to convert relative path (`var url`) to absolute by jQuery?

Script should do nothing, if it is already an absolute path.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting an absolute URL from a relative one. (IE6 issue)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470832/getting-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-one-ie6-issue)

Comment: @Phrogz here we have a better answer

Comment: No, @bobince's answer from that question is perfect.

Comment: $0.02: $('a').prop('href') will return the full url, too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if you use the `href` *property* instead of getting the *attribute*, you'll have a full url with domain:

```
$("a").live('click', function(){
    var url = this.href;    // use the property instead of attribute
    //do something
});
```

As noted in the question linked by @Phrogz, it sounds as though there are issues with IE6.

If you need to support it, you may need to build the `href` from the different parts like `this.host` and `this.pathname`. Those properties are supported by IE6. There are others you could use too, but you'd need to verify support.

jquery [live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) function deprecated in version 1.7 and removed from 1.9 so use alternate [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
    var url = this.href;    // use the property instead of attribute
    //do something
});
```

Comment: @Happy: In an event handler, `this` is a direct reference to the DOM element that received the event. When you do `$(this)`, you're taking that DOM element, and wrapping it in a jQuery object so you can use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: @Happy: You're welcome. Note that the question @Phrogz linked to shows an IE6 issue. I updated my answer. Also if you were hoping to avoid `hash` and other such data, you may want to use some of those other properties.

Answer (score 14):

Not what the OP asked, but if anyone is trying to do this for `<img>` tags (as I was when I found this Question), the secret it *not* to use jQuery's attr method.

This gives you straight contents of the src attribute (which if it's relative, will be relative):

`$('#your_img').attr('src')`

Whereas calling .src on the DOM object itself always gives you the absolute path (what I needed):

`$('#your_img').get(0).src`

Comment: ($('#your_img')[0]).src <--Just another way to look at what you wrote (Because I didn't fully catch it at first)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery mobile

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery.mobile.path.makeUrlAbsolute demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #myResult{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #108040;
    padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>The absoulte URL used is http://foo.com/a/b/c/test.html</p>
    <input type="button" value="file.html" id="button1" class="myButton" data-inline="true">
    <input type="button" value="../../foo/file.html" id="button2" class="myButton" data-inline="true">
    <input type="button" value="//foo.com/bar/file.html" id="button3" class="myButton" data-inline="true">
    <input type="button" value="?a=1&b=2" id="button4" class="myButton" data-inline="true">
    <input type="button" value="#bar" id="button5" class="myButton" data-inline="true">
    <div id="myResult">The result will be displayed here</div>
  </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $( ".myButton" ).on( "click", function() {

      var absUrl = $.mobile.path.makeUrlAbsolute( $( this ).attr( "value" ), "http://foo.com/a/b/c/test.html" );

    $( "#myResult" ).html( absUrl );
 })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.path.makeUrlAbsolute/

Answer (score 0):

The modern way is:

```
const url = new URL('MyPage.aspx', location)
```

Which will turn the page into an absolute url object. Works even with `'/MyPage.aspx'` or `'../MyPage.aspx'` or `'../SiblingFolder/MyPage.aspx'`