# Expand partial URL into full (like in image.src)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an `onerror` handler for images that replaces them with a loading image and then periodically tries to reload them. The problem I'm having is that if the loading image fails to load, it goes into an infinite loop of failure. I'm trying to deal with this by checking if the URL is the loading image:

```
if(photo.src != loadingImage) {
    // Try to reload the image
}
```

Unfortunately, `loadingImage` can be a relative URL (`/images/loadingImage.jpg`), but `photo.src` is always a full URL (`http://example.com/images/loadingImage.jpg`). Is there any way to generate this full URL without passing the function any more information? Obviously I could pass it the host name, or require full URLs, but I'd like to keep this function's interface as simple as possible.

EDIT:

Basically what I want is to guarantee that if I do `photo.src = loadingImage`, that this will be true: `photo.src === loadingImage`. The constraint is that I know nothing about `loadingImage` except that it's a valid URL (it could be absolute, relative to the server, or relative to the current page). `photo.src` can be any (absolute) URL, so not necessarily on the same domain as `loadingImage`.

Comment: How are you getting the `loadingImage` variable?

Comment: The function looks like this: `function retryImage(photo, loadingImage) { /* stuff */ }`. So `loadingImage` could be anything. I want it to work whenever `loadingImage` is a valid URL.

Comment: You say that loadingImage and photo.src might be from different domains. if `loadingImage` is a relative URL, and isn't necessarily the same domain name as `photo.src`, how do you know what domain it's from? Is there a source URL you can tie it back to? If not, I don't know that you'll be able to accomplish what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Joshua Carmody: I editted the question to hopefully make it more clear. If `loadingImage` is a relative URL, it I want it to be handled like any other URL (so if it doesn't contain a scheme, it's relative to the current page, or the current page's server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple methods people have used to convert relative URLs to absolute ones in javascript:

- [StackOverflow - Getting an absolute URL from a relative one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470832/getting-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-one-ie6-issue)
- Debuggable.com - Relative URLs in Javascript

Alternatively, have you considered doing the opposite - converting the absolute URL to a relative one? If `loadingimage` always contains the entire path section of the URL, then something like this would probably work:

```
var relativePhotoSrc = photo.src;
if (relativePhotoSrc.indexOf("/") > 0 && relativePhotoSrc.indexOf("http://") == 0) {
    relativePhotoSrc = relativePhotoSrc.replace("http://", "");
    relativePhotoSrc = relativePhotoSrc.substring(relativePhotoSrc.indexOf("/"), relativePhotoSrc.length);
}
alert(relativePhotoSrc);
if (relativePhotoSrc != loadingImage && photo.src != loadingImage) {
    // Try to reload the image
}
```

There's probably a slightly more efficient/reliable way to do the string manipulation with a regular expression, but this seems to get the job done in my tests.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I considered turning the absolute URL into relative, but it's not necessarily the case that both images are on the same domain (it just happens to be that way in this case).

Comment: The `document.createElement("a")` trick in that first link looks like it should do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? The photo should either be a full URL or relative to the current document.

```
var url;
// There probably other conditions to add here to make this bullet proof
if (photo.src.indexOf("http://") == 0 || 
    photo.src.indexOf("https://") == 0 || 
    photo.src.indexOf("//") == 0) {
  url = photo.src;
} else {
  url = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/" + photo.src;
}
```

Comment: +1 This worked in my tests. But I'd add a check to make sure that photo.src doesn't already start with a "/" to make sure you don't add two of them. Like `url = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/')) + (photo.src.indexOf("/") == 0 ? "" : "/") + photo.src;` or something.

Comment: @Joshua, there are a number of things that can be done to improve it; however, if a url starts with a "/", it's supposed to be an absolute URL from the root of the server, so it shouldn't be handled as relative.

Comment: the specific example the asker gave started with a "/". It's relative in the sense that it doesn't include the domain name and protocol.

Comment: @Joshua, you're right, I was wrong to say that URLS starting with / are not relative. I'm not going to try to make this perfect, though, specially since it could lead to a rabbit hole

Answer (score 0):

Just check if they end with the same string:

```
var u1 = '/images/loadingImage.jpg';
var u2 = 'http://example.com/images/loadingImage.jpg'

var len = Math.min(u1.length, u2.length);
var eq = u1.substring(u1.length - len) == u2.substring(u2.length - len);
```

Comment: The URLs aren't required to have the same domain name, so making them both relative doesn't work.