# Getting absolute URL requested by XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript

Assuming `http://example.com/js/script.js` fires an AJAX request against some relative URL, how do I get the absolute URL that ended up being requested?

For example, if I request `image.png` from `http://example.com/js/script.js` I'd expect to get back `http://example.com/js/image.png`. If, however, I requested `/image.png` from the same URL I'd expect to get back `http://example.com/image.png`.

This question is tricky for two reasons:

1. <strike>I don't believe it's possible to get a script's URL from inside it.</strike> **UPDATE**: I incorrectly assumed that AJAX requests are issued relative to the script location. It turns out that they are issued relative to `location.href`. This simplifies the situation.
2. I don't believe that `XMLHttpRequest` exposes the request URL, not to mention its absolute form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't believe it's possible to get a script's URL from inside it.

For that, simply use `location.href`

A quick hack to get absolute url from a relative one could be :

```
function getAbsoluteURL(relative) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = relative;
    return a.href;
}
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470832/getting-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-one-ie6-issue) it could not work on Ie6 , but does it really matter ?