# How to get URL of an image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, url, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension, and I'm adding an `onmouseover` handler to each of the images on a page. When the user mouses over an image, it's URL should be stored in a variable. I know I can easily get the value of the `src` attribute of the image, but I want the full URL. The `src` attribute stores the path of the image on the server. For example, when you right click an image in Google Chrome, you get the "Copy Image URL" option, which copies the image's URL to the clipboard.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `imageElement.getAttribute("src")` or `$("img.something").attr("src")`, which reads the original markup, use `imageElement.src` property which will *always* give you the full URL.

```
var imgFullURL = document.querySelector('img.something').src;
```

or:

```
var imgFullURL = $('img.something')[0].src;
```

To extract host name, path name etc. - parse the url with [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor, which works in modern browsers or use the legacy method via creating a temporary `a` node.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the     src    property.

Comment: Yep, as far as I know every html attribute is mapped to a DOM property, which contains a processed value of the original markup attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location` to get the page you are currently on and the following will give you the URL parts you need:

```
window.location.protocol = "http:"
window.location.host = "stackoverflow.com"
window.location.pathname = "/questions/32828681/how-to-get-url-of-an-image-in-javascript"
```

So, likely, you will need `protocol`, then "//", then `host` and finally the image `src`.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Umm, what is the question you are trying to have answered? I'm pretty sure that answers the OP's question.

Comment: The question is about an image element's url. Your answer is about the page url. The only relevant word in your answer is `src` but it's not even clear how you propose to use it.

Comment: The OP was able to get the relative path of the image on the server using the src attribute, but they needed the absolute path. If you read the last line of my answer, you will see how you can build up the absolute path of the image using the protocol, host and src.

The example given in the code block is what would happen if you grabbed those values on this current page. I'm assuming OP understands this, as they marked the answer as correct.

Comment: Your answer won't work as is in case some image has a full url in the original `src` attribute, so if you like your roundabout way of getting this job done, you might want to add an example of how to handle this universally or at least mention it. And also you will want to handle the case of relative `src="image.png"` vs `src="/images/someimage.png"` :-)

Comment: Ah, and for a dessert `src="../../images/someimage.png"`

Comment: I'm with wOxxOm on this - the answer is simply wrong. It needs [more work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780350/convert-relative-path-to-absolute-using-javascript) to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

So the TL;DR is this:

```
(function() {

  const imageInfo = new Object();
  imageInfo.source = '';

  window.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    var currentElement = event.target;
    // console.log(event.target);
    if (currentElement.tagName === 'IMG') {
      // console.log(currentElement.outerHTML + "is a photo");
      imageInfo.source = currentElement.src;
      // console.log("src is :" + imageInfo.source)
      return imageInfo.source;
    }
  })
})();
```

See CodePen:

[How to find the src URL for a photo](https://codepen.io/trevor-rapp/pen/powOxgw) by [Trevor Rapp](https://codepen.io/trevor-rapp) on
[CodePen](https://codepen.io)

This is how I thought about solving the problem in the most basic steps:

1. get the function to fire.
2. get the function to add an event listener that will perform an action on a mouseover event.
3. make that action know what the mouse is currently over.
4. figure out if what the mouse is currently over is an image or not.
5. create logic that will respond if it is.
6. that action that logic should do is return the source URL.
7. I will need to store that source URL if I am going to have to return it.

Here are how each of those solutions looked:

1. get the function to fire.

*An IFFE is a great way to get a function to fire without having to worry about polluting the name space.*

```
//skeleton for an IFFE statement

(function() {

})();
```

2. get the function to add an event listener that will perform an action on a mouseover event.

*An event listener that could fire anywhere would have to be attached to the window or the document.*

3. make that action know what the mouse is currently over.

*This part will be combined with part 2.  Event listener's first parameter is what type of event you want to listen for -- in this case 'mouseover. So now our code looks like this*

```
(function () {
  window.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
  //do stuff here
  }
})()
```

4. figure out if what the mouse is currently over is an image or not.

*To figure out which element the mouse if currently over you would use Event.target.
The MDN definition for that is: *

> The target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched. It is different from Event.currentTarget when the event handler is called during the bubbling or capturing phase of the event.  --[Event.Target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

*So the code would then look like this: *

```
(function () {
  window.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
  //get the current element the mouse is over
  var currentElement = event.target;

  }
})()
```

5. create logic that will respond if it is.

*This was a little trickier since a photo or IMG can be presented in various ways.
I chose to create a solution for the simplest way, which is assuming that the web developer used the more syntactically correct version of an  tag.  However, there are many times when they may choose to apply a 'background-image' CSS property to a normal . Other things to consider could be the use of iframes, which can make detecting the attributes of child elements very frustrating since they don't allow bubbling to occur. To tell if an element is an , you can simply use `elem.tagName === "IMG"` for your logic check.  While not included in the above code, if you wanted to check if a div is using the 'background-image', you could use something like `element.getAttribute('style').includes('term')` and switch out 'term' for something like 'url' or 'jpg' or 'png.' Kind of clunky and hacky, but just a thought.  Anyway, the code would then become*

```
(function () {
  window.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
  //get the current element the mouse is over
  var currentElement = event.target;
        if (currentElement.tagName === 'IMG') {
           //do stuff
    }
  }
})()
```

6. that action that logic should do is return the source URL.

*Once you get the logic done and you have properly selected the element, then you can use `element.src` to get the source URL.*

7. I will need to store that source URL if I am going to have to return it.

*You can do this anyway you want, but I played around with instantiating an object since it sounded like the value would need to change often, but you didn't necessarily need to store previous values.*

*And so the final product could be something like this*

```
(function() {

  const imageInfo = new Object();
  imageInfo.source = '';

  window.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    var currentElement = event.target;
    // console.log(event.target);
    if (currentElement.tagName === 'IMG') {
      // console.log(currentElement.outerHTML + "is a photo");
      imageInfo.source = currentElement.src;
      // console.log("src is :" + imageInfo.source)
      return imageInfo.source;
    }
  })
})();
```