# Extract source link from <img> tags when a url is given using Javascript (Aimed at Facebook posts page)

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any method by which I can get url inside `<img>` tag from a link.

Eg: When I give a link of website, like a website or facebook page, I want to get all urls inside all the img tags in that site --> `<*img src="url">`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet that you can show us?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get URL of an image in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828681/how-to-get-url-of-an-image-in-javascript)

Comment: @Tushar No Bro nothing :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809051/how-to-get-all-the-image-sources-on-a-particular-page-using-javascript

Comment: @slow No Bro,my aim is that I will provide the url of a website and the program(Javscript) will get all img tags from it's source code and provide me the source link of all those images

Comment: Note that img src isn't always a URL

Comment: @ControlAltDel Iam aiming at Facebook posts page

Comment: To help get you started, it sounds like the general operation you're looking to perform is "site scraping" (or "web scraping"), specifically in JavaScript (though you could use any language really).  The idea is to make an HTTP request to a URL, receive its response as HTML, then parse that HTML to obtain the data you're looking for.  With this information you should be able to use your favorite search engine to get started.

Answer (score 1):

First send a request to a page, get the content and parse it to html. Then get all img tags by using `getElementsByTagName` method.

For example, if you want to get all img tags on https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, your code should be like below.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com').then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.text();
}).then(function (html) {

    // Convert the HTML string into a document object
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var imgTags = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
    console.log(imgTags);
    
    var imgTagArr = [...imgTags];
    imgTagArr.forEach(img => console.log(img.src)); //iterate the all img tag srcs
}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```

Example output:

[image: json]

Comment: Let me test it now,I think it should work,I want something like this.Plan in my mind is like this

Comment: Bro Iam getting an error in console like
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: How can I overcome that Error

Comment: @Scania_16, Google's server might block your request. You can try it with another url, like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. I updated the answer, just copy and paste it in console and see the output (like in screenshot below).

Comment: Bro That worked fine,But My actual aim was @ Facebook page,it didn't work it's till showing that same Same origin policy error

Comment: Your Answer is perfectly fine, but didn't help me incase of facebook posts page :(

Comment: @Scania_16, Facebook's server set CORS policy to deny external requests. So you can't send request to it and get a response. If you want to get a response from Facebook, you need to login to https://developers.facebook.com and follow the documents.

Comment: I've taken the developer account already,But is highly confused with all those things.I searched a lot,but all results were of high level programming and I'm a newbie to JavaScript :((

Answer (score 0):

Yup ,
**in Html** like `<img class="pqr" url ="xxxxxxx-yyy"/>`
**in Js file:**

```
const img =document.querySelector('.pqr')
img.src // <-- this will give the src of the image
```

Comment: No Bro,It Didn't Worked

Comment: I read the all comments . And i realized it is happen because of they setup CORS in their server that's way it happening