# How to get the URL a browser will follow when we click on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we click one `<a>` tag the browser gets redirected to the corresponding page, but there are some details. Consider the following examples:

```
<a href="../onepage.html">One Page</a>
<a href="http://example.com/onepage.html">One Page</a>
<a href="onepage">One Page</a>
<a href="onepage.html">One Page</a>
```

When we visit such page with a browser it will in some sense translate those. If the address of the page on which this is located is `http://www.example.com/pages/somepage.html` the first will be translated to a redirect to `http://www.example.com/onepage.html`, the second will stay as it is, the third will be translated to a redirect into `http://www.example.com/onepage` and the last one will also be like the third.

My question is: how can, using jQuery, we get those "translated versions" of the URLs? This is not the `href` since this will give the information "as is".

How can we get with jQuery the URL a browser will actually follow if one clicks the link?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to convert relative links to absolute ones. I think this question has been answered in multiple forms in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781678/6535935)

Rather than having urls as input, you can use a jquery selector to get say the first `<a>` tag using `$('a')[0]` (or use your favorite jquery method) and use that as the `link` variable used in the linked solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery with `.prop('href')`. This is one of the cases where there's a difference between `.prop()` and `.attr()`. `.attr()` returns the raw attribute from the DOM element, but `.prop` returns the `href` property that results from parsing the URL.

In plain Javascript these would be `element.href` and `element.getAttribute('href')`.

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  console.log('.attr: ' + $(this).attr('href') + ' .prop: ' + $(this).prop('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="../onepage.html">One Page</a>
<a href="http://example.com/onepage.html">One Page</a>
<a href="onepage">One Page</a>
<a href="onepage.html">One Page</a>
```