# Trying to make sonic annotator *keeps* failing

Tags: makefile

Trying to make install sonic annotator. I've added a lot of dependencies. The error I'm getting now is

```
supportprogs: test succeeded
helpfulflags: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Dataquay::RDFIncompleteURI'
  what():  Uri::Uri: Given string is not a complete absolute URI [with string "doap:download-page"]
./test-helpfulflags.sh: line 24: 125839 Aborted                 (core dumped) $r --skeleton $percplug > /dev/null
Test failed: Fails to run with --skeleton vamp:vamp-example-plugins:percussiononsets
*** Test FAILED
make[1]: *** [Makefile.runner:182: sonic-annotator] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/luke/Desktop/sonic-annotator-1.6'
make: *** [Makefile:164: sub-runner-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I am, as I ask the question, trying to use

```
vamp-rdf-template-generator doap:http://vamp-plugins.org/rdf/plugins/vamp-example-plugins vamp:vamp-example-plugins:percussiononsets
```

In the following folder

```
/usr/local/lib/vamp$ ls
libvamp-hostsdk.so  vamp-example-plugins.cat     vamp-test-plugin.cat
libvamp-sdk.so      vamp-example-plugins.n3      vamp-test-plugin.so
plugins.cpp         vamp-example-plugins.so
pyin.so             vamp-rdf-template-generator
```

I am not optimistic.

B4fore running ./configure and make, again. Another thing that is annoying me, is that whenever make fails to complete, trying make install or make again, shows there is nothing to do: but I still can't run sonic-annotator. Meaning I go and delete the folder and start from the beginning again...

Comment: Since there is no tag for sonic annotator perhaps it's best reach out to any of the maintainers. Chris was supposedly active recently: https://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/sonic-annotator/memberships

Comment: thanks. @Andreas may i please ask - all the hits involve scripts and i don't know how to run them - what is http://vamp-plugins.org/rdf/plugins/vamp-example-plugins#percussiononsets as an absolute uri?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the case that vamp-rdf-template-generator will not overwrite its previous actions, so I had to delete vamp-example-plugins, which was inside the vamp folder, and run the former command with the uri, correct above.

The uri I provided is fine, an absolute one. I checked it by running the java code here [Convert relative path to absolute using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780350/convert-relative-path-to-absolute-using-javascript) via jnode.

So make finishes without errors. I then ran make install, and there was nothing to do again. Have tried running make and make install with sudo, and nothing changes

```
~/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6$ sudo make install
( test -e Makefile.base || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.base /home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6/base.pro ) && make -f Makefile.base install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
( test -e Makefile.test-svcore-base || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.test-svcore-base /home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6/test-svcore-base.pro ) && make -f Makefile.test-svcore-base install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
( test -e Makefile.test-svcore-system || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.test-svcore-system /home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6/test-svcore-system.pro ) && make -f Makefile.test-svcore-system install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
( test -e Makefile.test-svcore-data-fileio || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.test-svcore-data-fileio /home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6/test-svcore-data-fileio.pro ) && make -f Makefile.test-svcore-data-fileio install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
( test -e Makefile.runner || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.runner /home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6/runner.pro ) && make -f Makefile.runner install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/luke/Downloads/sonic-annotator-1.6'
```

So the issue is solved without installation / success.