# Facebook API Share open graph Issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-share, share-open-graph

Since a few days ,

Facebook share via the implementation of share_open_graph no longer works correctly.
Its seems it's the open graphs metatags found on the og:url which are scraped.

Is anyone having the same issue ?

```
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'share_open_graph',
                    action_type: 'og.shares',
                    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                        object: {
                            'og:url': FBLink,
                            'og:title': FBTitle,
                            'og:description': FBDesc,
                            'og:image': FBPic,
                            'og:locale': 'fr_FR',
                            'og:image:width': 540,
                            'og:image:height': 281
                        }
                    })
                }, function (response) {
                    // Action after response
                })
```

Comment: that was a workaround anyway and it was only a matter of time until they remove it, just add the og tags in the website source.

Comment: Yes, but is was mainly used when you have to share dynamic data such a user results of a quiz, game etc...

Comment: But it was still only a workaround, Facebook announced quite a while back that the are removing the ability to overwrite these values at the time of sharing and did so for all other ways of sharing that I am aware off, so if the finally closed _this_ loophole now as well, you need to find something else. (As we said here numerous times already, that basically means you need to provide an individual URL for each individual combination of data you want to share.)

Comment: those quizes/games produce(d) a lot of spam, but if the result does not include a number, you can just generate a separate page for each result. or use an id as parameter and add the og tags in the source.

Comment: ref (1): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930183/javascript-facebook-share-dialog-with-open-graph-ogurl-not-working
ref (2): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006196/how-do-i-share-dynamic-content-using-facebook-sdk-in-angularjs
ref (3): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870767/facebook-stops-custom-parameters-image-title-description-through-fb-ui
... can anyone share this announcement from FB?