# How to get a URL by a relative path ? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var baseURL = "http://google.com/a/b/c/d.html";
var relativePath = "../../e.mp3";
```

I want get result `http://google.com/a/e.mp3` by `baseURL` and `relativePath`

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: did you tried the example by me

Comment: @KailashYadav Yeah, It's awesome and I +1 for it. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear. Please accept as answer then too :)

Comment: @KailashYadav I will, Just like to see if someone has another way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function resolve(url, base_url) {


  var doc      = document
    , old_base = doc.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]
    , old_href = old_base && old_base.href
    , doc_head = doc.head || doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
    , our_base = old_base || doc_head.appendChild(doc.createElement('base'))
    , resolver = doc.createElement('a')
    , resolved_url
    ;
  our_base.href = base_url;
  resolver.href = url;
  resolved_url  = resolver.href; // browser magic at work here

  if (old_base) old_base.href = old_href;
  else doc_head.removeChild(our_base);
  return resolved_url;
}
alert(resolve('../../e.mp3', 'http://google.com/a/b/c/d.html'));
```

Here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ecmanaut/RHdnZ/

Here it is user for something like same: [Getting an absolute URL from a relative one. (IE6 issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470832)

Comment: When just coping from another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470832 you could at least give credit to the original author.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

If you use Node.js you can use the [path](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html) module to normalize your path. If you don't use Node.js you can still use this module in the browser with the help of [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Obviously you would need to get rid of `d.html` from the `baseUrl` and append the `relativePath` before you call `path.normalize`.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Yaffle/1088850). It worked quite well for me as it covers also special cases where simpler solutions will fail.

```
function absolutizeURI(base, href) {// RFC 3986

  function removeDotSegments(input) {
    var output = [];
    input.replace(/^(\.\.?(\/|$))+/, '')
         .replace(/\/(\.(\/|$))+/g, '/')
         .replace(/\/\.\.$/, '/../')
         .replace(/\/?[^\/]*/g, function (p) {
      if (p === '/..') {
        output.pop();
      } else {
        output.push(p);
      }
    });
    return output.join('').replace(/^\//, input.charAt(0) === '/' ? '/' : '');
  }

  href = parseURI(href || '');
  base = parseURI(base || '');

  return !href || !base ? null : (href.protocol || base.protocol) +
         (href.protocol || href.authority ? href.authority : base.authority) +
         removeDotSegments(href.protocol || href.authority || href.pathname.charAt(0) === '/' ? href.pathname : (href.pathname ? ((base.authority && !base.pathname ? '/' : '') + base.pathname.slice(0, base.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + href.pathname) : base.pathname)) +
         (href.protocol || href.authority || href.pathname ? href.search : (href.search || base.search)) +
         href.hash;
}
```

You also need this helper function:

```
function parseURI(url) {
  var m = String(url).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').match(/^([^:\/?#]+:)?(\/\/(?:[^:@]*(?::[^:@]*)?@)?(([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#[\s\S]*)?/);
  // authority = '//' + user + ':' + pass '@' + hostname + ':' port
  return (m ? {
    href     : m[0] || '',
    protocol : m[1] || '',
    authority: m[2] || '',
    host     : m[3] || '',
    hostname : m[4] || '',
    port     : m[5] || '',
    pathname : m[6] || '',
    search   : m[7] || '',
    hash     : m[8] || ''
  } : null);
}
```