# Selenium/Python: how to insert an absolute url to all anchor tags with relative urls?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I call `get_attribute('innerHTML')` and get back the mark-up as a string, can I get the relative URLs converted to absolute URLs?

This does happen for tags with relative href content when I call `element.get_attribute('href')`

The final text will be used by another system and I won't be able to add a  tag.

If `get_attribute('innerHTML')` doesn't have an option to add a base URL, how might I convert all the relative URLs to absolute URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with JavaScript. See here for the actual solution: [Getting an absolute URL from a relative one. (IE6 issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470832/getting-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-one-ie6-issue)

And this Java code snippet for how to apply that using WebDriver:

```
String relative = ...; // get the relative URL from somewhere...
String absolute = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return (function(relative) { var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = relative; return a.href; })(arguments[0])", relative);
```

By the way, here's some more info about executing JavaScript with WebDriver (and passing parameters): [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)